# How can an Object implement an interface and the 'is' operator return false?

Tags: c#

I have an event handler where:

```cs
public void Handle (object sender, object[] parameters)
```

In the handler I have some code:

```cs
var _view = sender as ISomeInterface;

if(_view != null) { ... do stuff }
```

However, despite `sender` being of a type that implements `ISomeInterface`, the conditional fails.

What is even more strange is here is what my debugger shows me:

```
typeof(ISomeInterface).AssemblyQualifiedName
  When evaluated, the debugger shows:
My.Company.ISomeInterface, MyCompany.Common, Version=1.0.8025.23774, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

And also this it true according to the debugger:

```
sender.GetType().GetInterfaces()[4].AssemblyQualifiedName
  When evaluated, the debugger shows:
My.Company.ISomeInterface, MyCompany.Common, Version=1.0.8025.23774, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

And yet when I evaluate `sender is ISomeInterface`, this returns `false`. Can anyone help me understand how this is possible?

##### Edit#1

This same odd behavior also happens on a coworkers machine after checking out from version control, so it's not just my machine/OS/Software that has some sort of issue.

Comment: Are you sure its not hitting the same handle method more than once: one of the times with the expected type, and another with a different one?

Comment: Also, are you sure you don't have more than one `ISomeInterface` in your project, and are using the other one at runtime in the actual check?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21105437/11683?

Comment: what does `type(ISomeInterface).IsAssignableFrom(sender)` return?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Result of "is" expression returns false when run, but true when inspected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105437/result-of-is-expression-returns-false-when-run-but-true-when-inspected)

Comment: Show us a screenshot of the **VS > Debug > Windows > Modules** list when you’re at the breakpoint on the `is` operator. I’m confident you’ll see the same DLL listed twice, with a different load location.

Comment: "...after checking out from version control"  - are you storing binaries in source-control?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that somehow Visual Studio is loading the same dll from 2 different locations (how or why remains to be determined) but if you encounter this, put this in your debugger to check if the dll source is identical:

```
typeof(ISomeInterface).Assembly.Location
sender.GetType().GetInterfaces()[4].Assembly.Location
```

In my case, there were 2 different locations.  The version of the dll was the same but dotNet apparently does not allow types from different dlls (even if they are the same) to be used in this way.

Comment: What you describe was one of the answers on the question linked by GSerg. This question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @julealgon To be fair, it is buried on that page amongst a dozen other answers.

Comment: @Dai true that. I upvoted it as it seems like a common enough case.